# Error when initialise play services in gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

Once I add play services in gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

I getting such error in all files. Not sure why? Please help.

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

**R.id.map - the R shows error cannot resolve symbol R.**

the gradle

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
}
```

Comment: post your app gradle file. it'll helpfull.

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild` at first

Comment: @BoradHardik updated.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i did. still error.

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'`

Comment: show total `build.gradle` please

Comment: Try to clean the project and sync.